# Calendar not showing notiications for event reminders

Tags: notifications

It looks like the autostart entry that was bundled with the latest release with Calendar it's not running? At least not on my system.

[image: Terminal showing that there's an autostart entry at /etc/xdg/autostart]

I can always start the daemon by hand and all reminders will just work. I'm curious why is not starting as of right now. Is this an experimental thing? Will it be available in the upcoming version?

[image: elementary OS system settings screen]